# removing 1 million integers from an arraylist and linkedlist one by one from the end of both lists

Tags: java

I am trying to prove that adding 1 million integers to an arrayList and then deleting them 1 by 1 from the end vs doing the same thing with a linkedlist is faster or slower in milliseconds and seconds.. having issues with removing from the end of the arraylist and removing from the end of linkedlist. it gives me an indexoutofboundsexception. here is my code so far:

```
  package blah;

 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.LinkedList;

 public abstract class blah {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<Integer> Array = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    LinkedList<Integer> Link = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> Array1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    LinkedList<Integer> Link1 = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    long start;
    long stop;
    long result;
    start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    for (int i = 1; i <= 1000000; i++) {
        Array.add(0, i);

    }

    stop = System.currentTimeMillis();
    result = stop - start;
    System.out.println("ArrayList time : " + result + " milliseconds");
    System.out.println("ArrayList time: " + result / 1000 + " seconds");
    System.out.println("");

    start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    for (int i = 1; i <= 1000000; i++) {

        Array1.add(i);
       Array1.remove(i);
    }

    stop = System.currentTimeMillis();
    result = stop - start;
    System.out.println("ArrayList time : " + result + " milliseconds");
    System.out.println("ArrayList time : "  + result / 1000 + " seconds");
    System.out.println("");

    start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    for (int i = 1; i <= 1000000; i++) {
        Link.add(0, i);


    }

    stop = System.currentTimeMillis();
    result = stop - start;
    System.out.println("LinkedList time : " + result + " milliseconds");
    System.out.println("LinkedList time : " + result / 1000 + " seconds");
    System.out.println("");
    start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    for (int i = 1; i <= 1000000; i++) {
        Link1.add(i);
        Link1.remove(i); 

    }

    stop = System.currentTimeMillis();
    result = stop - start;

    System.out.println("LinkedList time : " + result + " milliseconds");
    System.out.println("LinkedList time : " + result / 1000 + " seconds");
     }
}
```

Comment: You're removing the `i-th` element in each loop iteration, but the array grows smaller each time, so eventually `i > arrayLength`. Why not just remove the first element (`0-th`) each time?

Comment: I want to remove 1 by 1 from the end of the list, would removing the first element each time do that?@Kon

Comment: *"I want to remove 1 by 1 from the end of the list"* Then why do you start with `i=1`? Use a backwards looping `for` instead.

Comment: @Tom how do you mean backwards? start from 1 million?

Comment: It might be worth looking into JMH for such tests.  (Once you get your head around it) It simplifies removing all the extraneous parts from the test and confirming the behaviour and timings you want.

Comment: @Tom Nice reference to a bad (wrong!) article. Reverse loop of `for (int i=0; i< lList.size(); i++)` is surely *not* `for (int i=lList.size()-1; i > 0; i--)`. If you can't spot the error, check if `0` is seen by both loops.

Comment: @Andreas That's not my page, so ... ;P (but you're right).

Comment: @Progamminnoob If you want to compare performance, you need to warm up the JVM, which is why you should use JMH. Also, why are you using `add(0, i)`? It is bad for performance in `ArrayList`. Use `add(i)` to add to the *end* of the list. Your question text also says "add 1 million integers, *then* delete them", but you do no such thing in your code. You're adding one and removing it immediate, 1 million times. A list of 1 million elements vs a list of max 1 element is totally different logic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a re-write of my original answer to clarify some things in my original response and to address the question a bit more *directly* than I had done previously.

Your code is doing this:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 1000000; i++) {
    Array1.add(i);
    Array1.remove(i);   // <<--- problem here
}
```

When you call `Array1.add(i)` you're adding the `i`th *value* into `Array1`. However, when you call `Array1.remove(i)` you're trying to remove the value at *index* `i`.

The fact that you add *value* `i` and then try to remove from *index* `i` means that you're not doing what you think you're doing.

Even in your first iteration, you end up with:

```
  0 
+---+
| 1 |   Array1.add(1)
+---+

  0 
+---+
| 1 |   Array1.remove(1): IndexOutOfBoundsException, only index 0 is valid
+---+
```

The remove operation is not trying to find the *value* `1` to remove it. It's trying to find whatever exists at *index* `1` in the array, which causes the exception.

Comment: The code is right, if the OP's code not work in that way, he programmed in a wrong way, it's not right initiate an array in 1 and just leave the 0 element there.